# footer doesn't display

Tags: php, footer

I'm trying to code in the file index.php, but the footer and the slider that is in the content.php file don't display.

index.php code:

```
<?php
get_header();
    if (have_posts()) :
         while (have_posts()) :
              the_post();
              get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
         endwhile;
    else:
         get_template_part('content');
    endif;
get_footer();
?>
```

footer.php :

```
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-content">
        <img class="logo" src="ressources/logoge.png" alt="logo AEG">
        <div class="contact">
            <h3>Contact</h3>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
             consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh</p>
        </div>
        <div class="conditions">
            <h3>Conditions generales</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
            consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rss">
            <h3>Reseaux sociaux</h3>
            <button>
                <img src="ressources/iicon.png">
            </button>
            <button>
                <img src="ressources/ficon.png">
            </button>
             <button>
                 <img src="ressources/ticon.png">
            </button>

        </div>
    </div>
      <?php wp_footer(); ?>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

content.php:

```
    <!-- Slideshow container -->
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="ressources/walpaper9.jpeg" style="width:1000px">
        <div class="slide-text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <h2>AEG TEST</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="ressources/walpaper6.jpeg" style="width:1000px">
        <div class="slide-text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <h2>AEG TEST</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="ressources/walpaper2.jpeg" style="width:1000px">
        <div class="slide-text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <h2>AEG TEST</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- The dots/circles -->
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="archives-container">
        <div class="archives">
            <div class="archives-preview">
                <h2>Base de données ADHEMAR et <br>
                 archives numerisées</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="archives-btn">
                <button class="btn">Archives online</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsletter-container">
         <div class="newsletter">
            <div class="newsletter-preview">
                <h2>Newsletter</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, <br>
                sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna </p>
            </div>
            <div class="newsletter-btn">
                <input class="lbl" type="text" id="textlabel" placeholder  ="Nom,Prenom">
                <input class="lbl" type="email" id="emaillabel" placeholder="email">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="archives-v2">
            <h2>Base de données ADHEMAR et <br>
            archives numerisées </h2>
            <div class="btnarchive">
                <button class="btn-archives-v2">Archives online</button>
            </div>
     </div>
    <div class="newsletter-v2">
        <h2>Newsletter</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, <br>
         sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna </p>
         <input class="lbl" type="text" id="textlabel" placeholder  ="Nom,Prenom">
         <input class="lbl" type="email" id="emaillabel" placeholder="email">
    </div>

    <div class="container-grid">
        <img src="ressources/wallpaper1.jpeg">
        <img src="ressources/walpaper2.jpeg">
        <img src="ressources/walpaper4.jpeg">
        <img src="ressources/walpaper4.jpeg">
        <img src="ressources/walpaper6.jpeg">
        <img src="ressources/walpaper2.jpeg">
        <img src="ressources/walpaper8.jpeg">
        <img src="ressources/walpaper9.jpeg">
        <img src="ressources/walpaper10.jpg">
        <img src="ressources/walpaper11.jpeg">
        <img src="ressources/walpaper6.jpeg">
        <img src="ressources/walpaper9.jpeg">
    </div>
    <?php wp_content(); ?>
<script>
    let slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        let i;
        let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
        if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
</script>
```

After a lot of modifications trying to find what is wrong, when I inspect the page, I can not see the footer.

Comment: WordPress does not have a function named `wp_content`, so what were you trying to do with that `<?php wp_content(); ?>` in your `content.php` template? Is that your custom function?

Comment: `the_content();` ?

Comment: If you can't see the footer at all then there was probably a fatal error that stopped the page from loading. Enabled `WP_Debug` to see any errors that might be occurring: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress. Trying to use a function that doesn't exist, like `wp_content()` would cause an error like this